# About notation in f.g. $k$-algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Let $A$ be a $k$-algebra f.g. This means that I can write $A=k(S)$, with $S$ a finite set?

Thank so much!

Comment: No, $A=k[S]$, where $S$ is finite (polynomial expressions in elements of $S$ with coefficients in $k$; $k(S)$ are rational functions on $S$)

Comment: Perfect, if you would like to post as an answer, I could accept. Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A $k$-algebra $A$ is finteley generated if there exists a finite set $S$ (possibly empty) such that $A=k[S]=\{ P(s_1,\ldots,s_n) \mid n\geq 0, P\in k[X_1,\ldots,X_n],s_1,\ldots,s_n\in S\}$.